# Protobuf: strange transformation int64 to Long

Tags: protocol-buffers, scalapb

The protobuf-file has the following declaration of method:

```
message GetRequest {
   int64 client_id = 1;
   google.protobuf.StringValue name = 2;
 }
```

It generate:

```
final case class GetRequest(
    clientId: _root_.scala.Long = 0L,
    name: scala.Option[_root_.scala.Predef.String] = None
)
```

I invoke method with different values of clientId and observe the behavior by Idea-debug.

As a result:

- Some values of clientId, for example 816645943620556288, passed successfully.
- But some another passed with strange transformation.  For example, for 12550491997690948864 last digits transforms to 912 (from 864).  So in fact method receive non correct argument: 12550491997690948***912***.       One more example 1267049198769094***768***   to 1267049198769094***656***

I suspect, some bytes shuffled or missed at the tail of passed value (while int64 transformed to Long).

But I'm not sure.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Comment: Including an hex dump of the encoded messages could help. You can then check them with e.g. https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/ to see if it is correct. I suspect some corruption is happening to the data after it has been encoded, typical reason would be passing it as text string instead of binary data.